# Regular expression to match T-SQL variable declarations

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is is possible, using a regular expression, to match all T-SQL variable names following a `declare` statement?

In the following, I'd like to match `Var1`, `Var2`, and `Var3`. I do not want to match later references to these variables.

```
declare
    @Var1 datetime,
    @Var2 int,
    @Var3 varchar(max)
```

I've been working on it for some time using RegexBuddy and can't seem to get it right. I'm starting to wonder if it's possible.

**EDIT**:

Here's what I've got so far. It only matches the first variable. I can't figure out how to match subsequent ones.

```
(?i:declare)\s+
(?:@([\w@$#]+)\s+(?:bigint|int|smallint|tinyint
|(?:(?:decimal|numeric)(?:\s*\(\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)\s*\))?)
|money|smallmoney
|(?:(?:float|datetime2|datetimeoffset|time|char|varchar|nchar
|nvarchar|binary|varbinary)(?:\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\))?)
|real|date|smalldatetime|datetime|text|ntext|image
|uniqueidentifier|xml))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, I simplified it a little (got rid of all the specific data types) but you can fix it up how you like:

```
(?i:declare|,)\s+?(?:(?<var>@[\w@$#]+)\s+(?<type>[\w()]+))+
```

The key is the very first part, you want to look for the keyword "declare" or a "," these are going to be your separators.  Now techinically this means it would also match on something like this:

```
@var1 int,
@var2 int,
@var3 int
```

But since this would be invalid T-SQL anyways, I'm letting that go.

Comment: It wasn't part of the original question, but I made a few changes so it matches types with multiple "arguments" -- eg: decimal(9,2) -- which yours doesn't do. `(?i:declare|,)\s+(?:(?:@(?<var>[\w@$#]+))\s+(?<type>\w+(?:\s*\([^)]+\))?))+`

Comment: Nice addition, I didnt think about that!

Comment: I thought it would work, but then it also matches `select @foo bar, @bar foo` (alias in a select)