# RegEx for declared variables in T-SQL-script

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a list of all declared parameters in an SQL-Script. Example: Given the script

```
declare @a int, @b numeric(1,2)
        ,@c varchar(20)

select @x foo, @y bar
```

I want to match `@a`, `@b` and `@c`, but not `@x` and `@y`. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135435/regular-expression-to-match-t-sql-variable-declarations) but it will also match `@y` (which is an undeclared parameter). The mentioned solution is :

```
(?i:declare\s+?|,\s*?)(?:(?<var>@[\w@$#]+)\s+(?<type>[\w()]+))+
```

I had to modify it, because it did not match `,@b`. However, how can I make the regex stop at the end of the declaration? This is, when a type definition `[\w()]+` is followed by some whitespace (without newline) followed by and EOL?

I just don't get it. Ah, the RegEx dialect is 'C#'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your regex a bit to be able to use the `\G` anchor:

```
(?i:declare\s+?|(?!^)\G)(?:(?<var>@[\w@$#]+)\s+(?<type>\w+(?:\([^)]*\))?))\s*(?:,\s*|$)
```

`\G` will match either at the start of a string (you probably don't particularly want that here, so I used a `(?!^)` to prevent that) or immediately where a match ended (that's what we need!).

I modified the `type` capture group to match a more proper type too:

```
(?<type>\w+(?:\([^)]*\))?))
```

You'll need the `MULTILINE` option active however (or add `(?m)` at the beginning of the regex).

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hO1hL0).

Comment: **Warning**: this will not match defined declarations i.e. `DECLARE @i int = 1`

Comment: Yep, allowing for that will make the exercise jump a difficulty. If you expect only numbers or strings, it's not as hard but when you start adding queries, then going the full way would be straying off the original question.